# How efficient are foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Very simple question: Which is more efficient?

1. A `DELETE` query on a parent table, followed by a `DELETE` query on a child table
2. A `DELETE` query on a parent table that results in a foreign key deleting rows from a child table

To explain further, I'm working with very large tables (holding a few million rows), and I'm just wondering if the integrity offered by foreign keys is worth the extra work that MySQL has to do, over just remembering to update/delete child tables. I'd like to know before I actually go ahead and update to use foreign keys ;)

Comment: Tradeoffs everywhere. Is the potential data corruption worth the performance gain? Would adding the keys and throwing more hardware at it be worth the performance boost and improved integrity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you think you can code yourself, the database can do at least as well, and without having to use the network to do it.

Use the foreign keys.

Comment: I understand that foreign keys are there for a reason, but I'm not convinced. The database is under frequent heavy load, and I've often found that I can get faster performance out of it by taking some work off of it and doing it in PHP instead (for instance, `JOIN` queries can be made faster by selecting from the first table, building a PHP array of IDs to get from the second table, then getting those rows from the second table and stitching them together in PHP). While I'm on this subject, what about triggers to prevent (for instance) more than 6 rows from having the same value?

Comment: @Kolink What you are suggesting doesn't make sense. It cannot possibly be more efficient to execute the same process via several client-server interactions rather than one. But I can only lead the horse to water ...

Comment: What I did with the `JOIN` is use two smaller queries to distribute the work more evenly. I'll give the foreign keys a try, but they'll be the first things to go if the database server starts thrashing.

Comment: @Kolink Doing the work in PHP doesn't take any load off the database whatsoever. The database still does 100% of the work. All you are doing is influencing the timing and adding network latency and bandwidth consumption. You are also shifting responsibility for database integrity from the database to the application, which has its own costs, which are measured in $, not in execution time.

Comment: Understood. I will take your advice into consideration with the creation of "version 2" of my project.